# Is it possible to publish an academic paper and file a patent simultaneously?

Tags: patent-pending

I have developed a new technology in the field of 3D positional audio. I have a working prototype.

I've been working closely with a company specialising in acoustic simulation, and they have offered to co-author an academic paper for presentation at an acoustics conference.

I like the idea of this, as I have never published an academic paper.

But I have another option: I have just been introduced to an investor who has the necessary know-how and financial resources to to put a patent on the technology.

So I am considering inviting him to go 50:50 on a patent.

My question is: Will publishing invalidate the patent?

The submission deadline for the paper is in a fortnight.  Is it possible to set the patent wheels in motion, so that the paper can be delivered detailing a "Patent Pending" technology?

Comment: I'm guessing you are not in the U.S. In what countries might you want to get a patent? The U.S. has different rules than most other places.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve your rights to ultimately file in any country (that is part of the Paris Convention or abides by it - essentially everywhere) you need to file *somewhere* by the day of publication. It Can be a regular application or can be a provisional application. A very few countries, notably the U.S., have a grace period allowing filing up to a year after the article is published.